# Empty rewrite.log on Windows, RewriteLogLevel is in httpd.conf

Tags: apache-2.2, mod-rewrite

I am using mod_rewrite on Apache 2.2, Windows 7, and it is working ... except I don't see any logging information.

I added these lines to the end of my httpd.conf:

```
RewriteLog "c:\wamp\logs\rewrite.log"
RewriteLogLevel 9
```

The log file is created when Apache starts (so it's not a permission problem), but it remains empty. I thought there might be a conflicting `RewriteLogLevel` statement somewhere, but I checked and there isn't.

What else could cause this?

Could this be caused by Apache not flushing the log file? (I closed it by hitting CTRL-C on the httpd.exe command ... this caused the access logs to be flushed to disk, but still nothing in rewrite.log)

**My (partial) httpd-vhosts.conf:**

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    ServerName my.domain.com
    DocumentRoot c:\wamp\www\folder

    <Directory c:\wamp\www\folder>
        Options -Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride None
        Order allow,deny
        allow from all

        <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
            RewriteEngine On
            RewriteBase /

            RewriteRule . everything-redirects-to-this.php [L]
        </IfModule>
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Not having any rewrites, forgetting `RewriteEngine on` and not making any requests that hit rewrites *could* all cause it.  Where are your rewrites defined?

Comment: @Ladadadada - I have `RewriteEngine On` and the actual rewrites inside a Virtual Host, inside a Directory (in httpd-vhosts.conf). I have made requests that hit rewrite.

Comment: "Inside a `<Directory >`" sound suspicious.  Could you add that part of your config to the question?

Comment: @Ladadadada - Added.

Comment: I'm starting to run out of ideas.  Might be time to see what Apache has to say about it.  What's in your error log?

Comment: @Ladadadada - sadly, nothing relevant.

Comment: how about, switch to linux ?

Answer (score 0):

How about adding your error log in your vhost like i do for each vhost, ie something like:

```
<VirtualHost *>

    ServerAdmin webmaster@xxx.fr
    DocumentRoot "/web/htdocs/olivier/xxx/prod/website"

    ServerName xxx.fr
    ServerAlias *.xxx.fr
    ErrorLog "/web/logs/xxx.error.log"
    ...
    ...
    ...

</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Nothing interesting there: http://pastebin.com/iUrT73hm

Answer (score 0):

[I think this is a WAMP bug, based on this thread.](http://forum.wampserver.com/read.php?2,76608)

Comment: Welcome to Server Fault! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score 0):

I'm far from an apache guru, but I did notice you had:

```
AllowOverride None
```

under

My understanding is that this needs to be:

```
AllowOverride All
```

Comment: The `AllowOverride` directive has [nothing to do with this problem](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#allowoverride).